# Why do type 1 diabetics experience hypoglycemia?

Tags: diabetes-mellitus

I know that type 1 diabetics do not produce enough (possibly none) insulin since beta cells of pancreas are damaged and as far as I know glucagon is produced by alpha cells (which are healthy in diabetic body, I suppose). So, my question is that since glucagon is released when the blood glucose is low, why do the diabetics experience hypoglycemia? Shouldn't the glucagon be released and increase the blood sugar?

---

Note that in [Role of Alpha Cells in Diabetes](http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/452112)<sup>1</sup>, the following is stated:

> Glucagon responses to hypoglycemia have been known to be blunted in
>   type 1 diabetes of long duration, and this may be a result of a loss
>   of alpha- and beta-cell communication secondary to insulin deficiency.

---

1. Rudy W Bilous. Role of Alpha Cells in Diabetes - Medscape - Apr 11, 2003.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this on your own? Can you show us what you found?

Comment: @anongoodnurse What I found is that it [*may be a result of a loss of alpha- and beta-cell communication secondary to insulin deficiency*](http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/452112).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Key to this question is that untreated, type 1 diabetics would never have hypoglycemia.  **It is insulin treatment that causes the hypoglycemia.**  Insulin brings sugar down and without insulin (as the case with type 1 diabetics) sugar just goes up.    Exogenous insulin will bring sugar down in anyone, diabetic or no.  Since Type 1 diabetics use insulin all the time, there is more chance for an accident (hypoglycemia).

Also, some Type 1 diabetics might not compensate against hypoglycemia or correctly perceive that they are hypoglycemic.  Reasons for this are laid out in the following article:

From [Hypoglycemia in Type 1 Diabetes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3279554/)

> Three major defects in this homeostatic response contribute to the
>   high frequency of hypoglycemia in type 1 diabetes.

The article summarizes what those are - basically a blunting of normal reactions to hypoglycemia stemming from the disease itself.  It then summarizes:

> Thus, the glucose counterregulatory defense against hypoglycemia in
>   individuals with diabetes becomes impaired at almost every level and
>   rendered even more defective through intensive insulin therapy